# direct update failing in MFP 8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When I am trying to do direct update for my app then I am getting below error. I am using **MobileFirst 8.0.0.00-20170220-1900**

```
[8/17/17 17:21:29:813 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[8/17/17 17:21:29:813 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[8/17/17 17:21:29:814 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[8/17/17 17:21:29:814 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[8/17/17 17:21:29:814 CDT] 000f8292 BaseTransacti < com.ibm.mfp.admin.actions.BaseTransaction run RETURN
[8/17/17 17:21:29:814 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[8/17/17 17:21:29:814 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[8/17/17 17:21:29:814 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[8/17/17 17:21:29:814 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[8/17/17 17:21:29:814 CDT] 000f8292 ApplicationSe > com.ibm.mfp.admin.util.ResponseUtil errorImpl ENTRY
[8/17/17 17:21:29:815 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[8/17/17 17:21:29:815 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[8/17/17 17:21:29:815 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[8/17/17 17:21:29:815 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[8/17/17 17:21:29:815 CDT] 000f8292 ApplicationSe E   FWLSE3000E: A server error was detected.
                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.worklight.admin.configservice.datastore.ConfigServiceException: FWLSE3208E: An invalid status code "500" was returned. The response content is "{"reason":"internal_error","details":"The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred."}".
    at com.ibm.mfp.admin.actions.ArtifactDeploymentTransaction.persist(ArtifactDeploymentTransaction.java:766)
    at com.ibm.mfp.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.prepare(BaseTransaction.java:552)
    at com.ibm.mfp.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.internalRun(BaseTransaction.java:454)
    at com.ibm.mfp.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.run(BaseTransaction.java:327)
    at com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.v2.ApplicationService.addWebResource(ApplicationService.java:1146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:183)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
    at com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:43)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:473)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.ibm.mfp.admin.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:61)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.filter.HSTSFilter.doFilter(HSTSFilter.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:912)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.ibm.worklight.admin.configservice.datastore.ConfigServiceException: FWLSE3208E: An invalid status code "500" was returned. The response content is "{"reason":"internal_error","details":"The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred."}".
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.configservice.datastore.ConfigServiceClient.createOrUpdateAttachment(ConfigServiceClient.java:618)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.configservice.datastore.ConfigServiceStoreManager.createorUpdateAttachment(ConfigServiceStoreManager.java:139)
    at com.ibm.mfp.admin.actions.ArtifactDeploymentTransaction.persist(ArtifactDeploymentTransaction.java:758)
    ... 82 more

[8/17/17 17:21:29:817 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[8/17/17 17:21:29:817 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[8/17/17 17:21:29:817 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[8/17/17 17:21:29:817 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[8/17/17 17:21:29:817 CDT] 000f8292 DataStoreClou > com.ibm.worklight.admin.datastore.DataStoreCloudantUtil useCloudant ENTRY /mfpadmin
[8/17/17 17:21:29:817 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[8/17/17 17:21:29:818 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[8/17/17 17:21:29:818 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[8/17/17 17:21:29:818 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[8/17/17 17:21:29:818 CDT] 000f8292 JNDIUtils     1   JNDI Access found in cache for context mfpadmin and key mfp.db.cloudant.username => null
[8/17/17 17:21:29:818 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[8/17/17 17:21:29:818 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[8/17/17 17:21:29:819 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[8/17/17 17:21:29:819 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[8/17/17 17:21:29:819 CDT] 000f8292 ContextProper 2   Found property mfp.db.cloudant.username=null in JNDI cache.
[8/17/17 17:21:29:819 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[8/17/17 17:21:29:819 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[8/17/17 17:21:29:819 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[8/17/17 17:21:29:819 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[8/17/17 17:21:29:819 CDT] 000f8292 ContextProper 1   JNDI Access via getContextProperty in /mfpadmin to mfp.db.cloudant.username => null
[8/17/17 17:21:29:820 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[8/17/17 17:21:29:820 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[8/17/17 17:21:29:820 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[8/17/17 17:21:29:820 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
[8/17/17 17:21:29:820 CDT] 000f8292 DataStoreClou < com.ibm.worklight.admin.datastore.DataStoreCloudantUtil useCloudant RETURN false
[8/17/17 17:21:29:820 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl getAll:255 DeploymentRegistryImpl: getting all- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: []
[8/17/17 17:21:29:820 CDT] 000f8292 DeploymentReg 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.deployment.registry.DeploymentRegistryImpl get:198 DeploymentRegistryImpl: get (one)- type: com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsDynamicConfigurationImpl returned: null
[8/17/17 17:21:29:821 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:51 Entering method: getAdditionalPackages().
[8/17/17 17:21:29:821 CDT] 000f8292 AnalyticsConf 1 com.ibm.mfp.server.core.internal.configuration.analytics.AnalyticsConfigurationDeploymentHandler getAdditionalPackages:54 Exiting method: getAdditionalPackages() with value 'null'.
```

Comment: The issue seems to be around the web archive. Was direct update working earlier and you started facing the issue?

Comment: This is the first time I am trying direct update.

Comment: Could you try uploading another update? Just to check if there was a problem with the earlier archive.

Comment: I tried tried that but I am facing the same error.

Comment: I do not have the same build, but direct update works fine on a later iFix build ( that I have). Do you want to try deleting your application registration and try it once more? Or try upgrading iFix level